# How can I detect the current browser and device in an C# web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, browser-detection

I'm trying to detect the current web browser and Device (PC，mobile) within  in my program using C# Web API.

Everywhere I look people say to use Request.Browser, however I can't get that to work. 
Any suggestions or is there something I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't. Modern browsers are constantly changing and evolving. Any decision based on things that you currently know are true or false about particular browsers will be out of date by the time you ship your code. Use *feature detection* instead, which relies on detecting the *current characteristics* of the browser. (I.e. many sites making bad assumptions about what IE supports was the reason why IE11 completely changed its user agent string to try to *evade* sites using browser detection)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Really? It 's ShocK

Comment: @BugFinder And When I use other Device (phone、pad) to call webapi, it show "Unknown". How can I do?

Comment: I have naver seen UserAgent header to contain "Unknown" with whatever devices. What devices you test on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Request.Headers.UserAgent
```

Is probably you best bet. It doesn't give you the browser straight away and can easily be manipulated. But from the user agent there is probably some library to get the browser.

Comment: And When I use other Device (phone、pad) to call webapi, it show "Unknown". How can I do?

Comment: You can't. If the device is not sending that information or some other header identifying itself it's impossible for the API to know what device it was.

Answer (score 0):

try this

var deviceType=HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent

Comment: And When I use other Device (phone、pad) to call webapi, it show "Unknown". How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

"User-Agent" header attribute can be used to detect the device type and operating system.
Here are a helper class you can use in this case.

```
public class DeviceDetectorHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public DeviceDetectorHelper(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detects the device and operating system information and returns a string describing the device and OS.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///   A string describing the detected device and operating system.
    /// </returns>
    public string DetectDeviceAndOS()
    {
        string userAgent =  _context?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

        bool isMobile = IsMobileDevice(userAgent);
        string operatingSystem = DetectOS(userAgent);

        string deviceType = isMobile ? "Mobile" : "Desktop";

        return deviceType+" "+operatingSystem;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the user agent string corresponds to a mobile device.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userAgent">The user agent string to be checked.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   A boolean value indicating whether the user agent string corresponds to a mobile device.
    /// </returns>
    private bool IsMobileDevice(string userAgent)
    {
        // List of common keywords in mobile user agent strings
        string[] mobileKeywords = { "Mobi", "Android", "iPhone", "iPad", "Windows Phone" };

        foreach (string keyword in mobileKeywords)
        {
            if (userAgent.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detects the operating system information based on the provided user agent string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userAgent">The user agent string to be used for operating system detection.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   A string representing the detected operating system or an empty string if the OS is not recognized.
    /// </returns>
    private string DetectOS(string userAgent)
    {
        if (userAgent.Contains("Windows NT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (userAgent.Contains("Windows Phone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return "Windows Phone";
            }
            else if (userAgent.Contains("Win64", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return "Windows 64-bit";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Windows 32-bit";
            }
        }
        else if (userAgent.Contains("Macintosh", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return "macOS";
        }
        else if (userAgent.Contains("Android", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return "Android";
        }
        else if (userAgent.Contains("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return "iOS (iPhone)";
        }
        else if (userAgent.Contains("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return "iOS (iPad)";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to Inject the "IHttpContextAccessor" into you DI container.
Now you can call this function DetectDeviceAndOS() and it will return a string contains device type "Mobile" or "Desktop" and the OS "Windows" "macOS" ... as implemented above